# Cannot increment beyond endIndex

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm looking for the "Swift 3" way of handling an error where I try to increment the position of a string to an out of bounds index. I have an extension that looks like the following:

```
extension String {
  func substring(from: Int) -> String {
        let fromIndex = index(from: from)
        return substring(from: fromIndex)
  }
}
```

In implementation code, I have a loop which periodically takes chunks of a string and moves the index further in the string. My problem is I'm not sure what the Swift 3 way is of handling "End of String, do not proceed if we've reached the end"

Implementation code is something as trivial as this:

```
myStr = myStr.substring(from: pos + 1)
```

if `pos + 1` is the end of the string, it shouldn't error out, but should instead just exit/return from my loop. What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: Make your function return an optional String, and if the index is out of bounds then return nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write something like this

```
extension String {
    func substring(from offset: Int) -> String {
        let fromIndex = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
        return substring(from: fromIndex)
    }
}
```

Examples

```
"Hello world".substring(from: 0) // "Hello world"
"Hello world".substring(from: 1) // "ello world"
"Hello world".substring(from: 2) // "llo world"
```

### What does happen if you pass the wrong param?

Something like this will generate a fatal error.

```
"Hello world".substring(from: 12)
fatal error: cannot increment beyond endIndex
```

You can make you code safer adding a guard statement like this

```
extension String {
    func substring(from: Int) -> String? {
        guard from < self.characters.count else { return nil }
        let fromIndex = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: from)
        return substring(from: fromIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `index(_, offsetBy:, limitedBy:)` method 
to ensure that the index is not advanced beyond the end index:

```
extension String {
    func substring(from: Int) -> String? {
        guard let fromIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: from, limitedBy: endIndex) else {
            return nil
        }
        return substring(from: fromIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```swift
extension String {
    func substring(from index: Int) -> String {
        guard index < characters.count else { return "" }
        return substring(from: characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index))
    }
}

"12345".substring(from: 3) // "45"
"12345".substring(from: 9) // ""
```

Alternatively, you might want to return `nil` if `index` is out of bounds when you change the function's return type to `String?`